# Is Oracle Linux with Red Hat compatible kernel identical to RHEL?

Tags: centos, rhel, oracle-linux

With CentOS dying and being reincarnated as an upstream beta of RHEL, I have been searching for alternatives that can be used in production. Oracle Linux emerges as the most likely candidate. I understand it offers either its UEK or a Red Hat compatible kernel.

I have certain backup applications that are sensitive to kernel changes. How close is Oracle Linux's non-UEK kernel to Red Hat? What are the differences, if any?

Thank you.

Comment: Frying pan and fire comes to mind with some choices. Have you looked at [Rocky Linux](https://rockylinux.org/)?

Comment: You're right, that is exactly why I posted this question - I was afraid of jumping into something unsavory, but the fact that Oracle Linux is the exact same that their enterprise customers use - and that Oracle itself uses for infrastructure - was encouraging. I looked at Rocky and Alma, and they're exciting but pretty new, so I wonder how "good" they would be for production, and how long they might be around.

Comment: And if you don't like the direction Oracle choose to go in? Either choice is not risk free but I personally would go for rocky (depending on the level of support you are likely to need). I had heard that the Rocky development team are experienced and many have defected from CentOS.

Comment: You hit on another good point. Oracle offers a Red Hat compatible kernel for those who need a strict Red Hat environment, but they push their own Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel really hard, because it offers certain advantages and better performance with their database software. So far they haven't done anything "evil." They offer the OS for free in order to increase market share and hopefully pick up support contracts down the line I guess. I will most likely wait until the end of the year to see what happens with Alma and Rocky, I really hope they succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For years, I've kept the Oracle Linux in my wallet of "things to try" and replace CentOS with.

With the announced discontinuation of CentOS as an RHEL clone, I did give it a try.

I quickly found that there is no version parity between packages.

More info can be found on [this post](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/choosing-your-rhel-8-clone-centos-replacement).

The `selinux-policy` package in Oracle Linux 8 has a *different* version scheme to that in RHEL 8. To be specific, the EVR (complete version, as in "epoch-version-release"). For example:

Oracle Linux: 3.14.3-67.**0.1**.el8

Original (RHEL), AlmaLinux, Rocky Linux: 3.14.3-67.el8

This makes Oracle Linux not really a clone of RHEL, because there is quite an obvious issue of being unable to install some `-selinux` packages that were built in RHEL itself, or other clones. These extra bits *0.1* in the release field were enough to break the compatibility.

So whatever you are to choose, I can't recommend Oracle Linux as a CentOS 8 replacement. For whatever reason, they had this change in the version scheme, and this finding may be just a tip of an iceberg of other potential changes or incompatibilities.

Comment: That's a helpful observation. I actually wouldn't mind sticking with Oracle's repos only. I guess the extent of the compatibility is that you'd be able to compile from source, but not install directly from non-Oracle repos. But it is a valid and valuable point.

Comment: oracle has also been known to spontaneously end all support for projects like this, see opensolaris, so Oracle Linux could very well end up like CentOS (as far as its free support goes)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle claims that the Red Hat compatible kernel is [compiled directly from the RHEL source code](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/about-oracle-linux-and-the-unbreakable-enterprise-kernel.html)